# How to display User Control Property in visual studio properties browser

Tags: wpf, properties

Good afternoon,

I am using WPF.

I have the following class:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private TimeSpan timeMinutesInterval;

    public TimeSpan TimeMinutesInterval
    {
        get { return timeMinutesInterval; }
        set { timeMinutesInterval = value; }
    } 

    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TimePickerNew_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

What do I need for the property TimeMinutesInterval appears in the visual studio properties browser?

Thank U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the control to another control/window/etc., you can see the property under the Miscellaneous section of the properties window for that added control.  Is that what you were looking for?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 TimeMinutesInterval="0:5:0" />
</Grid>
```